# TableView index from rootcontroller to detailcontroller (UINavigationController)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

My root view is a grouped tableview. When the user selects a row, i want to be able to retain which row was selected to give to the detailcontroller for loading the correct data.

All the navigation is working fine, I just don't want to have to create a global variable to just retain the index. Is there a built in method for the navcontroller or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to follow up with how I ended up coding this. I'm still somewhat new to Obj-C, so some concepts I haven't dealt with or come across, so if this is old hat, sorry.

You can create your data element in the child controller and pass the data 1 for 1 directly to that element by accessing its property.

```
ParentController.h

NSDictionary *myData;


ChildController.h

NSDictionary *childData;


// This would get called in the parent controller where appropriate
// but before the child controller is presented
ChildController.childData = myData;
```

This is obviously very stripped down, but the idea works. Just take your data and pass it to the property before calling it and it will be there once the child view is presented. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can either set a property in you detail view controller before it is *pushed* giving info about the row selected so it can influence the behaviour of the detail view controller, or it is possible to access the parent view controller directly from the detail view controller with:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIViewController *parentViewController
```

I prefer the first option - you can write a custom `init...` method, to supply the data for the detail view controller when it's created.

There isn't a *builtin* way as such, you should try and make the view controllers de-coupled as possible so they can be re-used and are resistent to changes elsewhere in the app.

This is a useful quote from the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1):

> With the exception of view controllers managing leaf data, each custom view controller must provide a way for the user to navigate to the next level of the data hierarchy. A view controller that displays a list of items can use taps in a given table cell to display the next level of data. For example, when a user selects a photo album from the top-level list, the Photos application creates a new photo album view controller. The new view controller is initialized with enough information about the album for it to present the relevant photos.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I did ultimately figure it out by accident. I was able to pass my NSDictionary directly to the NSDictionary in the childController by accessing its property. childController.myDict = [otherDict objectForKey:@"someName"]; Thanks for the help.